# Memory Management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.2

I need a clarification from all of you,That is I am implementing an iPad application. In that I tried to download and animate the images. The image count should be more than 100,000.The code I used to download and adding to the view is as follows.

```
UIImageView* imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,100,100)];
NSData *receivedData=nil;
receivedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://path/prudently/iphone/image_s/e545afbf-4e3e-442e-92f9-a7891fc3ea9f/test.png"]];
imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData] ;
[subView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

But I am getting exception after I successfully added more than 8000 image to my subview. I am getting exception at getting data from the url. And one more thing I am not releasing the subview because once I downloaded them I need to animate the subview.

Please give me your suggessions

Thank you,
Sekhar Bethalam.

Comment: What exception are you getting? You may have run out of memory, in which case the exception will probably be in `+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` or one of the methods it calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the URL , images or something to a cached file, and divide some pages to animate the  images...
When the user press a page link , application read and animate the images of this page, images of the page which user don't use need not display.

Answer (score 1):

100,000 images would seem a lot for desktop applications, let alone a smart phone like an iPhone.  Is there not another approach you can take to solve this problem that wouldn't need such a high resource count?

Comment: @David: 
Hi I got this Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")

Answer (score 0):

The only way you are going to accomplish this is to dynamically create and destroy the UIImageViews as they are needed on the screen. The iPhone/iPad/iAnything are incapable of doing what you want because of the limited memory available on the device.

Comment: But I had a problem with these I am not able to destroy them because the subview should be animated till the application closed. This is the requirement. If I do As you suggested I can't animate them. That is the problem,

Comment: I don't understand the value of animating 100,000 100x100 pixel objects on a screen that can only show, at most (iPad), 70 instances of each image not overlapped.